# Prevent Require Cycle warnings on terminal

Tags: react-native, intellij-idea, expo

I'm continuously getting **Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.** warning on my terminal and it has make debugging my program so difficult.

I have used

```
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
  'Require cycle:', 
])
```

and also

```
console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

But neither worked. YellowBox.ignoreWarnings worked only for the warnings displayed on the mobile but not for the warnings on the terminal of my IDE. How can i prevent getting these warnings on the terminal.

Comment: there is no way to hide them, neither the IDEA terminal nor from the system one AFAIK. `YellowBox.ignoreWarnings` and `console.disableYellowBox` only affect devices/simulators

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I commented out the below lines and they stopped appearing in both terminal and the device.

node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js (Line 114)

> ```
>   console.warn(
>     "Require cycle: ".concat(cycle.join(" -> "), "\n\n") +
>       "Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. " +
>       "Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle."
>   );
> ```

After commenting out that warning, restarting the project fixed my issues.
PS. I'm using expo.

Answer (score 10):

My solution for this issue, hope it helps others:

```
import { AppRegistry, LogBox } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Require cycle:']);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: This works well, used with RN 0.70.7

Answer (score 0):

I commented out the console.warn in `node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js` Line 10.

```
console.warn = function warn(...args) {
    // if (args.length > 0 &&
    //     typeof args[0] === 'string' &&
    //     (/^Require cycle: .*node_modules/.test(args[0]) ||
    //         /Use UIManager\.getViewManagerConfig\('LottieAnimationView'\) instead\./.test(args[0]) ||
    //         /ReactNative\.NativeModules\.LottieAnimationView\.getConstants/.test(args[0]))) {
    //     return;
    // }
    // originalWarn.apply(console, args);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I went for a safer way :) I used patch-package to make sure I still see my own mistakes... mhm... require cycles :)

metro+0.59.0.patch

```
diff --git a/node_modules/metro/.DS_Store b/node_modules/metro/.DS_Store
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..21ab2f3
Binary files /dev/null and b/node_modules/metro/.DS_Store differ
diff --git a/node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js b/node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js
index 8c04756..3b208f6 100644
--- a/node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js
+++ b/node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js
@@ -114,11 +114,14 @@ function metroRequire(moduleId) {
         .map(id => (modules[id] ? modules[id].verboseName : "[unknown]")); // We want to show A -> B -> A:
 
       cycle.push(cycle[0]);
-      console.warn(
-        `Require cycle: ${cycle.join(" -> ")}\n\n` +
+      const cycleString = cycle?.join(" -> ");
+      if (!(cycleString?.startsWith('node_modules/'))) {
+        console.warn(
+          `Require cycle: ${cycleString}\n\n` +
           "Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. " +
           "Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle."
-      );
+        );
+      }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hiding Yellow boxes is not a solution, it's a kind of patch. You should look into your code actually there problem would be your components will be requiring each other. Like you make a component A which imports B and in B, you import A. If you please show your full logs, I'll further tell you the exact components.

Comment: This is the correct way to go. Require cycles usually can be fixed joining modules or rearranging them. This post has a good and clear explanation of the problem: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/06/25/circular-dependencies-javascript/